# How to convert a created EXE file back to Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyinstaller

How do I convert a EXE file created with PyInstaller back to a `.py` file?

I already tried `python-exe-unpack-master`, but that didn't work. Further I've seen this article: [How do you reverse engineer an EXE "compiled" with PyInstaller](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/160/how-do-you-reverse-engineer-an-exe-compiled-with-pyinstaller) but I don't know how to extract the EXE's append data.

Is there a other way? Or can someone explain me more about the method I gave.

Answer (score 2):

You can extract the contents of the .exe file using PyInstaller Extractor. Run it like this:

```
python pyinstxtractor.py executable.exe
```

You will get your python file.

Comment: Its not recognized. Do I need to install Pyinstyaller extractor appart from Pyinstaller, or Is there A certain directory where I need to be, or did you just misspell it?

Comment: Nvm my last comment

Comment: Listen I already tried this, It gives me 204 pyc files, wich I can uncompyle with uncompyle6, but my code isnt in one of those py files

Comment: Please use this url and help yourself buddy.
https://github.com/countercept/python-exe-unpacker/blob/master/pyinstxtractor.py

Comment: @Pythonologist I already was there, but I couldnt figure out how I could get my code back, that the reason why Im on this forum...